# Few questions about smart contract I created (just start learning)

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

I just started learning solidity and have some questiones about the smart contract I created for pratice/fun. 
Please let me know if any of my concepts are inaccurate, appreciate for all the advices and suggestiones.

**Description**:

the concept of this smart contract is really simple, whoever send the bigger amount of ether into the contract wins, it will pair you with whoever is before you (if no one is before you, you are player_one) and it will reset after 2 player are played (so it can be played again)

**Code:**

```
contract zero_one {

address public player_one;
address public player_two;
uint public player_one_amount;
uint public player_two_amount;


function zero_one() public{
    reset();
}

function play() public payable{
    //Scenario #1 Already have two player in game, dont accpet new player. do I even need this check at all? since smart contract execute serially i should never face this condition?
    if(player_one != address(0) && player_two != address(0)) throw;

    //Scenario #2 First player enter the game
    else if(player_one == address(0) && player_two == address(0)){
        player_one=msg.sender;
        player_one_amount = msg.value;
    }

    //Scenario #3 Second player join in, execute the game
    else{
        player_two = msg.sender;
        player_two_amount = msg.value;

        //check the amount send from player_one and player two,  whoever has the bigger amount win and get their money 
        if(player_two_amount>player_one_amount){
            player_one.transfer(player_one_amount+player_two_amount);
            reset();
        }
        else if(player_two_amount<player_one_amount){
            player_two.transfer(player_one_amount+player_two_amount);
            reset();
        }
        else{
            //return fund back to both player
            player_one.transfer(player_one_amount);
            player_two.transfer(player_two_amount);
            reset();
        }
    }
}

function reset() internal{
    player_one = address(0);
    player_two = address(0);
    player_one_amount = 0;
    player_two_amount = 0;
}
}
```

**Questions**

- When sending ether back to users, do I need to calcualate how much
  gas is going to take? or would smart contract automatically deduct
  the gas from the amount i am going to send
- Is it correct to set reset() as interal since i only want it to be
  called within the smart contract, it shouldn't be called by anyone else
- Would Scenario#1 ever happen? since from what I understand
  smart contract do not have to worry about race condition and it
     should never be in that state?
- 4. Is adding playable to play correct? ( since user are going to send ether with this call)
- Is using throw a bad practice? (warning on remix)
- transfer vs send, why is it better to use transfer?
- I coded this smart contract as a practice. I can already see that if
  someone want to game the system, he could just wait for someone to be player_one and check the amount player_one send(after the block is mined) and just send a bigger sum than that. Is there anyway this exploit could be stopped? Is there other security/flaws I did not see?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> When sending ether back to users, do I need to calcualate how much gas
>   is going to take? or would smart contract automatically deduct the gas
>   from the amount i am going to send

The gas limit specified when executing a transaction needs to cover all activity end-to-end. This includes calls out to other contracts, transfers, etc. Any gas not used after the transaction is mined is returned to you.

> Is it correct to set reset() as interal since i only want it to be
>   called within the smart contract, it shouldn't be called by anyone
>   else

`internal` is fine for what you're intending to do. But, it's more like `protected` access. A sub-contract can call `internal` methods. `private` provides the strictest visibility.

> Would Scenario#1 ever happen? since from what I understand smart
>   contract do not have to worry about race condition and it should never
>   be in that state?

No, it should not happen. You are correct that transactions are processed serially, so you don't really have to worry about race conditions. That doesn't mean you shouldn't have this sort of protection in your code though...

> Is adding playable to play correct? ( since user are going to send
>   ether with this call)

Yes. Any method that is expecting to receive wei and uses `msg.value` needs to be marked as `payable`.

> Is using throw a bad practice? (warning on remix)

`throw` is deprecated. You want to use one of `revert`, `require`, `assert` as of 0.4.13. The one you use depends on the type of check you're doing and if gas should be refunded. See [this](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/control-structures.html?highlight=require#error-handling-assert-require-revert-and-exceptions) for more details.

> transfer vs send, why is it better to use transfer?

`send` and `transfer` are similar. The difference is that `send` limited the amount of gas sent to the call, so if the receiving contract tried to execute any logic, it would most likely run out of gas and fail. In addition, failures during `send` would not propagate the error and simply return `false`. [Source](https://vomtom.at/solidity-send-vs-transfer/)

> I coded this smart contract as a practice. I can already see that if
>   someone want to game the system, he could just wait for someone to be
>   player_one and check the amount player_one send(after the block is
>   mined) and just send a bigger sum than that. Is there anyway this
>   exploit could be stopped? Is there other security/flaws I did not see?

Security is a much more in depth topic. Any data sent in a transaction is visible, so you can't hide the exploit you mentioned unless you use a private blockchain. You can encrypt data sent in a transaction yourself, but I don't believe you can encrypt sending ether.

In terms of other security issues, there are several tools out there that perform security checks on contracts. I'd suggest looking into one of those. Also, read through the [security considerations](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/security-considerations.html) page on the Solidity documentation.

Comment: Hi @Adam Kipnis , for the last question related to security. Is it possible for smart contract to know when it is mined? For example to fix the exploit , is there a way to code the smart contract in the following way . ---If only player_one is there, then forfeit and return the money when the block is mined (make sure that the game is only being played when there are two player)

Comment: Did I understand answer 1 correctly as the following: 
Whoever trigger the play() function in this contract has to send enough gas to supply all the actions play() going to trigger. (Including the part where it send back the fund to player). smart contract itself wont need to supply any gas since the user are suppose to supply it (and the smart contract will throw if not enough gas is given)

Comment: Again really appreciate for the response :)

Comment: “If only player_one is there,...”. Not sure I understand your question. `play()` needs to be called twice in your contract in 2 separate transactions from 2 different accounts that are mined (likely at different times in different blocks). If you want to impose a time limit for a 2nd player to join, you can enforce that in your code.

Comment: For your second comment regarding gas, you have the general idea. Generally speaking, you wouldn’t do the transfer in `play()`. You would calculate how much an address is owed and store that in your contract state. Then, a separate `withdraw()` method would be used to collect the winnings. See http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/common-patterns.html

Comment: Thank you for point to the withdraw pattern, it is really helpful :)